# Trying to understand how node, NPM and GIT integrate together

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Apologies in advance if any of these questions have already been asked but I am a bit of a noob in this area.

Firstly I'd like to say that I have been taking the courses on Freecodecamp (Which is awesome) and I now believe I am ready to start my first project. I haven't done all the courses yet and I will be going back to them soon enough but I know html, CSS and JS. The questions I have are not around using Node, NPM and GIT but how they all tie together and what happens in between. It's hard to explain exactly what I'm trying to say so I'll jump straight in with an example.

I learn best by reverse engineering and I want to build a website like https://witcher3map.com/. They have it all available on GitHUB here https://github.com/witcher3map/witcher3map so I decided to see if i could  set it up on my machine and reverse engineer it etc. I know some bits and not others so I'll write my questions out like I'm following their instructions and ask questions when I need to:

**Questions**

- I installed node and GIT and cloned the repo with no issues. Now my
  first question around this is that I created a folder called
  witcher3map but when i cloned it, it created another folder called
  witcher3map. So now, it is witcher3map/witcher3map. Can i just
  move it up one folder or does GIT somehow save these paths and other config info somewhere
  and it will make GIT get confused?
- i then ran NPM install - Now I believe NPM looks at the
  package.json file to find out what dependencies it needs to DL, is
  this correct?
- Once the dependencies are downloaded, if i then sync the repos again does it upload the dependencies to GIThub? I obviously don't want this and if it does I assume there is a switch or some command to prevent this from happening?
- The next command tells me to run "grunt build" but when i try this it errors. I think it's because I don't have Grunt installed? But the instructions don't tell me to install it. Even when it is installed can someone tell me how "build" gets executed? I guess it goes to a sub folder and loads a grunt config type file which has the build instructions in it but how does it get there?

**EDIT**: Some more info - Grunt is a dependancy and it downloaded it fine. When i run "grunt build" I am running from the GIT Bash CLI and it says "command not found", do I need to run it in node rather?

- The same goes for "grunt server"

I have also seen in other projects other commands I am finding hard to understand. For example on https://github.com/WFCD/warframe-items it says that after cloning the repo, to use the app you type

> const Items = require('warframe-items')

I mean what does that mean? I'm sure it makes sense to seasoned DEVs but not me. Can anyone elaborate on this?

My final question is that on some other projects I also see commands/switches where they say things like "build" or ways to build a DEV build or prod build. How do I trace those said commands to ultimately open a file to see exactly what "build" does?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So now, it is witcher3map/witcher3map. Can i just move it up one folder or does GIT somehow save these paths and other config info somewhere and it will make GIT get confused?

It's fine to move it. All history for any repo in git is stored locally within the "relative root" of the folder (that's what the `.git` folder is). Thus moving the whole project in totality will do nothing to git.

> i then ran NPM install - Now I believe NPM looks at the package.json file to find out what dependencies it needs to DL, is this correct?

Correct. There are other things that can happen (reverse cascade lookup if you are unspecific in the semantics of the `package.json` file), but `npm install` is just designed to find and install x package(s).

> Once the dependencies are downloaded, if i then sync the repos again does it upload the dependencies to GIThub?

It shouldn't, take a look at the .gitignore file in the witcher repo you linked. It's configured as a blacklist, things that git should *not* pay attention to. `node_modules` is in that list.

> Some more info - Grunt is a dependancy and it downloaded it fine. When i run "grunt build" I am running from the GIT Bash CLI and it says "command not found", do I need to run it in node rather?

Never used grunt personally (more of a gulp / npm native / webpack person), but it seems just as with other popular task runners, you may have to install it globally. That's what the `-g` flag means in:

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

https://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Run that command first, then proceed with the instructions from the repo.

> Even when it is installed can someone tell me how "build" gets executed? I guess it goes to a sub folder and loads a grunt config type file which has the build instructions in it but how does it get there?

`Gruntfile.js` is where the config lives.

Essentially Grunt is just the "conductor of the orchestra". It initializes the package dependencies you downloaded with `npm install` (which live inside `node_modules`) with the relevant config files (if they don't look for them automatically).

For example `server.js`, that's the config file for the express package listed in your package.json file. This essentially makes nodeJS a web server environment (i.e. locally establishes a loopback address on port whatever, when you make a request in your browser, node is listening and responds).

As for how NodeJS knows about this stuff that would take more time to explain than im willing to invest, but the hint is : that's why you had to install grunt globally.

Final tips:

1. You are thinking about this too much like a jigsaw puzzle, it's more like a jenga tower, layers on layers.
2. Git is on it's own layer, separate from grunt / nodeJS.

P.S. Answered this because i had free time (*cough* covid19, no work), but you should probably post questions like this either on the freecodecamp forums or reddit for better reception.

Comment: hmm, I added a comment earlier to say thx but it looks like it didn't stick

Comment: Anyway you were right about the grunt needing to be installed globally. I can get further now. Out of interest why do you say I should post these questions on freecodecamp? Is this not the best place?

Comment: StackOverflow is meant more for troubleshooting / coding errors, not explaining basic principles behind things to new developers. Also put bluntly, if you had searched each individual question on here, you probably would've found the answers.